# I Want to Load Store Procedure Without Using EF

Tags: c#

[image]

Load the Store Procedure without using EF I Faced this Problem. I want to load the SP list type

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/205233)

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I'm not getting error but i can't get the result

Comment: @Av.Raj That is because you are passing the reader as the result. you need to extract and build the type you want serialized and returned.

Comment: ExecuteScalar using time i got only one object but i want list (CustomerId,CustomerName) so I changed ExecuteReader but now i'm not getting any results

Comment: using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["Customer"]));
                    }
                }

Comment: i used this one but still i'm not getting any result

Comment: how to write the list for ExecuteReader output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the sample below. Its also shows how to read the records from the StoredProcedure execution in your C# Code.
Also its a good practice initiating the SQLConnection and SQLCommand object in Using Block.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SearchCustomer";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // Use below line if you want to pass any parameter values to SP.
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", CustomerId);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // Read Column based on Column Name. Below sample reads String column
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("columnName"));
            // Read Column based on Column Index. Below sample reads int column 
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Want To Create a Dropdown List That list load the CustomerName with id. i'm used angularjs for dropdown list. now i want get the datas from my DB used SP

Comment: I don't need pass any parameter just load my SP output into my JsonResult  then i can send that result my angular file

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "SearchCustomer";
                //add any parameters the stored procedure might require
                cnn.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("columnName")));
    }  }
cnn.Close();
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Hi @Av.Raj, please find updated answer based on your comment above. 2 ways of reading data is shown in sample. One is by column name and another is by column index.
Note: No need of cnn.Close() when using the using() block. Connection will be closed and disposed by the runtime.

Comment: You can read the values from SP as in the sample and use it your way to bind to the DropDownList.